# Are there any easy ways to create a YouTube playlist or download queue from a text file?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

In other words, if I have a list with entries formatted "[Artist Name] - [Track Name]" without advanced knowledge of their corresponding YouTube URLs (if any exist), how might I script things so that YouTube searches for each entry, and generates the URLs for the first *n* number of identical or similar entries per a YouTube query?

Do any simple solutions come to mind that might lever wget, PowerShell, or Python?

Answer (score 3):

[roll.io](http://roll.io) seems to do exactly what you want, except for the download queue.